# How to access the URI in a GameObject Script in D3D Unity C# project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I build D3D C# project from Unity, the new solution has two projects: the Main project and Assembly C-Sharp. However the GameObject Script is in Assemnly C-Sharp which is class library for Main project.

[this picture describe my recent project solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBC0H.png)

How can I send message or any parameter from App.cs of Main project to GameObject Script (Throwing.cs).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do . You mean send a message from 1 scene to another????

Comment: @NoobProgrammer no I build an UWP (Mixed Reality) from Unity. Because my object is loaded from external link so I need to send the link from App.cs to a script file attached with a game object